# Redux connect does not pass `dispatch` to connected component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

please have a look at my code:

```
const Checkout = ({items, setItemAmount}: CheckoutDisplayProps, dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getOrders());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return <CheckoutDisplay items={items} setItemAmount={setItemAmount} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => {
  return {
    items: state.checkout.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  return {
    setItemAmount: (id: number, amount: number) =>
    dispatch(setItemAmount(id, amount)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Checkout);
```

what I am trying to achieve is to `dispatch` action in `useEffect` hook, I expect to have `dispatch` passed to `Checkout` component by `connect`.

It turns out that `dispatch` is not being passed as a function, it is just an empty object. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: Connect does not pass the dispatch function to the component it just makes a bridge between the component and the redux state manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  When you supply a value for `mapDispatch`, you no longer get `props.dispatch` automatically.  It's up to you to include it as a prop if desired, but most of the time you don't need it because you're just calling bound action creators inside the component.

See [the React-Redux usage guide for `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) and [the Redux FAQ entry on "why don't I have `props.dispatch`?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-dont-i-have-this-props-dispatch-available-in-my-connected-component) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using hooks, just use `useDispatch`, and `useSelector`.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Checkout = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const items = useSelector(state => state.checkout.items);

  const setItemAmountCallback = (id: number, amount: number) => {
    dispatch(setItemAmount(id, amount));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrders());
  }, []);

  return <CheckoutDisplay items={items} setItemAmount={setItemAmountCallback} />;
};
```